# what's different between wpdb->prefix and table_prefix

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

what's different between wpdb->prefix and table_prefix
i want to install db table of my plugin
for example

```
$wps_user_visits_table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix.'wps_user_visits';
```

is equal to

```
$wps_user_visits_table_prefix = $table_prefix.'wps_user_visits';
```

or diffrent ?

Comment: What is `table_prefix`? Where is it coming from? That does not look like normal standard WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is pretty simple.

`$wpdb->prefix` is getting the `prefix` field from global `$wpdb` object.

`$table_prefix` can be anything. Most probably it's some local variable that contains the same value, but you can assign anything to that variable.

So using `$wpdb->prefix` is a better idea - it's nicer, cleaner and more obvious.

Comment: as you said i don't need $table_prefix and instead of always i can use $wpdb->prefix; yes ? or no ?

Comment: Yes, `$table_prefix` is just some local variable - it doesn't come "from" WordPress so it's impossible to say what it is exactly.

Comment: what about base_prefix?

Comment: @LucasBustamante what about it? base_prefix is not a WP default variable/constant…